# How to check what class belongs AnyObject?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

For example, there are two models Realm Information

```
    import Foundation
    import RealmSwift

    class Music: Object {

        dynamic var id = ""
        dynamic var title = ""
        dynamic var url = ""
    }
    class DownloadMusic: Object {

        dynamic var id = ""
        dynamic var title = ""
        dynamic var path = ""
    }
```

And there is a certain function

```
func test(object: AnyObject) {

}
```

When a call is transferred as an argument 'realm.objects(Music)[0]'

```
let realm = try! Realm()    
test(realm.objects(Music)[0])
```

Can I check in function, the object belongs to a class 'Music' or to a 'DownloadMusic'

Comment: How about `if object is Music` and `if object is DownloadMusic` ?

Comment: @vacawama's suggestion is probably the most elegant and swifty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
func test(object: AnyObject) {
    if object is Music {
        print("music")
    } else if object is DownloadMusic {
        print("downloadmusic")
    }
}
```