# whats the equivalent of java's instanceof in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Just like java's instanceOf keyword whats the equivalent in Swift?

java example:

```
A a = new A();
boolean isInstanceOfA = a instanceof A;
```

Here isInstanceOfA is true

So i need something similar in Swift

Comment: try operator "is": a is A

Comment: nevermind I found the answer in one of stackoverflow chat rooms

Comment: or maybe I should delete this question if its already answer, a link to a similarly asked question would be good.

Comment: You can use `is` operator
An example can be found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/36900103/4791032

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`isKindOfClass()` method, from NSObjectProtocol is the equivalent of java's instanceof keyword, in java it's a keyword but in swift it's a protocol method, but they behave similarly and are used in similar contexts.

> `isKindOfClass:` returns YES if the receiver is an instance of the
>   specified class or an instance of any class that inherits from the
>   specified class.

Which is exactly what instanceof keyword does in Java [related link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

Example:

```
let a: A = A()
let isInstanceOfA: Bool = a.isKindOfClass(A) // returns true.
```

Also you can use the `is` keyword

```
let a: A = A()
let isInstanceOfA: Bool = a is A
```

The difference:

- `is` works with any class in Swift, whereas `isKindOfClass()` works only with those classes that are subclasses of `NSObject` or otherwise implement `NSObjectProtocol`.
- `is` takes a type that must be hard-coded at compile-time. `isKindOfClass:` takes an expression whose value can be computed at runtime.

So no `is` keyword doesn't work like `instanceof`

Comment: AFAIK there aren't any cases where isKindOfClass is required. I would strongly suggest the answer is amended to make clear that `is` would be the preferred usage.

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ the intention here is to provide all available options and what exactly it does thereby giving a "Complete" answer.

Comment: Yeah and that's fine, but given that it's Objective-C and not Swift and thus will be unavailable on any platform not including the Objective-C runtime, isKindOfClass is a platform specific alternative, not the Swift equivalent.

Answer (score 23):

For **swift3** and **swift4** it's:

```
if someInstance is SomeClass {
    ...
}
```

if your class is extending `NSObject` you can also use:

```
if someInstance.isKind(of: SomeClass.self) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is actually valid from Swift 1.0

Answer (score 16):

```
let a = A()
let isInstanceOfA = a is A
```

Comment: then this begs the question whats the difference between `isKindOfClass` method and `is` keyword

Comment: `is` takes a type that must be hard-coded at compile-time. `isKindOfClass:` takes an expression whose value can be computed at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

For **Swift 4.x** it's:

```
func getOrElse<T>(defaultVal:T) -> T {
    if let selfVal = self, selfVal is T {
        return selfVal as! T
    } else {
        return defaultVal
    }
}
```

**Very short variant**(by suggestion **@Sulthan**):

```
extension Optional {
    func getOrElse<T>(defaultVal:T) -> T {
        return (self as? T) ?? defaultVal
    }
}
```

Comment: You know that this would be easier to implement using `(self as? T) ?? defaultVal`?

Comment: Unlike Java, in Swift optionals are a native type and there are language operators that work with them. Thats why you rarely have to define new methods on Optional - the necessary funcionality is already there.

Answer (score -1):

With [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c) it's `isKindOfClass:[ClassName class]`.

With [swift](/questions/tagged/swift) it's `isKindOfClass(Classname.class())`.